# datatables - adding/merging the values of one table to another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

A new project requires that we have two servers set up to accept requests.  Originally we had a reporting system which queried a database and brought back various details to the user.  We now obviously need to query two database on seperate servers and merge this information to provide real-time reporting.

My plan is to query both databases seperately and write these values into datatables (which will always have the same columns as the two databases are designed identically) and then try to merge these two datatables and then databind this to a grid view.  i have it working to a point but don't know what to do next...the queries all work OK and I am able to pull both sets of sql queries into seperate datatable, what I don't know how to do is merge these so that any data (of the same date for example) is added to give a total from the two servers, and where a date exists on one database but not the other, this should still be displayed...i hope this is clear enough.

When I use this:

```
tblBreakdownA.Merge(tblBreakdownB, False, MissingSchemaAction.Add)

        GridViewBreakDown.DataSource = tblBreakdownA
        GridViewBreakDown.DataBind()
```

The two datatables do merge, however the second simply merges below the first so I end up with some dates repeated but holding different values, i.e

DB 1 
01 jan - 10 hits
03 jan - 15 hits
04 jan - 5 hits

DB 2 
02 jan - 5 hits
03 jan - 10 hits
05 jan - 5 hits

What I am seeing output is something like this:
01 jan - 10 hits
03 jan - 15 hits
04 jan - 5 hits
02 jan - 5 hits
03 jan - 10 hits
05 jan - 5 hits

And what I am looking for should be something like this
01 jan - 10 hits
02 jan - 5 hits
03 jan - 25 hits
04 jan - 5 hits
05 jan - 5 hits

Any help is, as always, very much appreciated!

**EDIT - Source Code added**

Below is more code to better explain what I am trying to achieve.

```
'*******POPULATE GRIDVIEW-BREAKDOWN CONTROL**************
    Dim tblBreakdownA As DataTable 'holds results from Database A
    Dim tblBreakdownB As DataTable 'holds results from Database B

    GridViewBreakDown.Visible = True
    lblBreakdown.Visible = True

    'Connection to Database A
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection
        myConnection.ConnectionString = CONNECTION STRING
        Dim mySelect As New SqlCommand
        mySelect.Connection = myConnection
        mySelect.CommandText = "SELECT STATEMENT"
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = mySelect.ExecuteReader()

        tblBreakdownA = New DataTable("Breakdown")
        tblBreakdownA.Load(myReader)

        myReader.Close()
        myConnection.Close()
    End Using

    'Connection to Database B
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection
        myConnection.ConnectionString =CONNECTION STRING
        Dim mySelect As New SqlCommand
        mySelect.Connection = myConnection
        mySelect.CommandText = "SELECT STATEMENT"
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = mySelect.ExecuteReader()

        tblBreakdownB = New DataTable("Breakdown")
        tblBreakdownB.Load(myReader)

        myReader.Close()
        myConnection.Close()
    End Using

    tblBreakdownA.Merge(tblBreakdownB, False, MissingSchemaAction.Add)

    GridViewBreakDown.DataSource = tblBreakdownA
    GridViewBreakDown.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is grouping.  You could do this with Linq or T-SQL, but in essence you're looking to group the records by date, and display the sum of the hits within that group.

Grouping examples:

[Linq to SQL Group By](http://csainty.blogspot.com/2008/01/linq-to-sql-groupby.html)

[T-SQL Group By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

EDIT:

I hope @Rene147 doesn't mind me adapting the code he posted to demonstrate the Linq syntax you would need (its a bit longwinded and heck of a mess but it works and demonstrates some of Linqs' neat features...):

```
Public Sub StackTest()
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable

    '   Create some test data
    dt1.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
    dt1.Columns.Add("Hits", GetType(Integer))

    dt2.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
    dt2.Columns.Add("Hits", GetType(Integer))


    dt1.Rows.Add(#1/1/2011#, 10)
    dt1.Rows.Add(#3/1/2011#, 15)
    dt1.Rows.Add(#4/1/2011#, 5)

    dt2.Rows.Add(#2/1/2011#, 5)
    dt2.Rows.Add(#3/1/2011#, 10)
    dt2.Rows.Add(#5/1/2011#, 5)

    '   Merge the two results
    dt1.Merge(dt2)

    dt1.DefaultView.Sort = "Date"

    Dim results = (From anomList In
                   (From mergedTables In dt1.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "Date", "Hits").AsEnumerable
                    Select [Date] = mergedTables.Item(0), Hits = mergedTables.Item(1))
                Group anomList By anomList.Date Into g = Group
                Select New With {.[Date] = [Date], .Hits = g.Sum(Function(n) CInt(n.Hits))}).OrderBy(Function(n) n.Date)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, there is a GROUP BY being used in the SQL statements to get the data in a format that I need, but can you use a GROUP BY to combine two datatables (or even to group two seperate sql statements that use different connection strings?)

Comment: @allanmayberry88 I've edited my post to combine @Rene147's test case with Linq required to do what you asked.  It could probably be done easier than that but I broke it down into baby steps which made the statement much longer than I expected =/ sorry.  Hope it helps though!

Comment: @Smudge202 - Thanks for getting back to me, I'll have a look at your suggestion and see if it works - I've added more code to my question which maybe makes it a bit clearer as to what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: I see now.  The code I've posted still applies.  I'm not brilliant at front end components but the results variable I declared in my code is a collection of an anonymous type which has the Properties for Date and Hits.  You should be able to switch out my results declaration for "GridViewBreakDown.DataSource = <linq statement>" (or simply GridViewBreakDown.DataSource = results)

Comment: Much appreciated! I'll come back to you once tested! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i've added your code, and i've ran into a few small problems (probably because I dpn't fully understand the code yet!) although it looks as if the tables have merged OK, the Grouping doesnt seem to work properly and I am just getting the values of one table displayed.  Also, the date is no longer displaying within the gridview when the code is executed, any suggestions? (code below)

Comment: `Dim results = (From anomList In
(From mergedTables In tblBreakdownA.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "dt_created", "TotalCount").AsEnumerable Select [dt_created] = mergedTables.Item(0), TotalCount = mergedTables.Item(1)) Group anomList By anomList.dt_created Into g = Group Select New With {.[dt_created] = [dt_created], .TotalCount = g.Sum(Function(n) CInt(n.TotalCount))}).OrderBy(Function(n) n.dt_created)`

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you've asked for but 100% agree with Smudge it would be far better to do a GroupBy in the SQL statment

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable

    '   Create some test data
    dt1.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
    dt1.Columns.Add("Hits", GetType(Integer))

    dt2.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
    dt2.Columns.Add("Hits", GetType(Integer))


    dt1.Rows.Add(CDate("01/01/2011"), 10)
    dt1.Rows.Add(CDate("03/01/2011"), 15)
    dt1.Rows.Add(CDate("04/01/2011"), 5)

    dt2.Rows.Add(CDate("02/01/2011"), 5)
    dt2.Rows.Add(CDate("03/01/2011"), 10)
    dt2.Rows.Add(CDate("05/01/2011"), 5)

    '   Merge the two results
    dt1.Merge(dt2)

    dt1.DefaultView.Sort = "Date"

    '    Select all of the distinct dates 
    For Each row As DataRow In dt1.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "Date").Rows

        Dim TotalForDay As Integer = 0

        TotalForDay = HitsOnGivenDate(row.Item(0), dt1)
        TotalForDay += HitsOnGivenDate(row.Item(0), dt2)

        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Date - {0} had {1} hits", row.Item(0), TotalForDay))
    Next

End Sub

Private Function HitsOnGivenDate(ByVal SearchDate As Date, ByVal SearchTable As DataTable) As Integer

    Dim HitsOnDay As Integer = 0

    Dim SearchString As String = String.Format("Date = '{0}'", SearchDate)

    '   Selete all the rows for this given date
    For Each Row As DataRow In SearchTable.Select(SearchString)
        HitsOnDay += Row.Item(1)
    Next

    Return HitsOnDay
End Function
```

Comment: Because I love the .ForEach() lamda expression for confusing colleages, the following line does the same as your loop - but cooler of course =D  dt1.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "Date").AsEnumerable.ToList.ForEach(Sub(n) String.Format("Date - {0} had {1} hits", n.Item(0), (HitsOnGivenDate(CDate(n.Item(0)), dt1) + HitsOnGivenDate(CDate(n.Item(0)), dt2)).ToString))